# Why I am getting request for /recieved { [Error: ENOENT, open ''] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '' } error?

Tags: node.js, nodes

As I am executing this code, it gives me errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT' error .
I have written a simple html hello world page.
it should simply print hello world when running on the port 3000 but everytime it is showing the same error. 
My present version of node is v0.10.38

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

var pathname =url.parse(request.url).pathname;

console.log("request for "+ pathname + "recieved");

fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        response.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    }else{
        response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data.toString());
    }
    response.end();
});
}).listen(3000);

console.log("server running at 3000");
```

Comment: What is the result of `pathname.substr(1)`? Are you sure this result points to an existent file? Or it might have a typo?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the application? Are you sure it's a valid path being read from?

Comment: pathname.substr(1) is giving only '/', but I have tried var pathname = __dirname+"/index.htm"; , but all the time giving the same result

Comment: `pathname.substr(1)` gives me empty string, as your error is telling you. There is no file empty string to read, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine for me.  I think when you send the request, you are asking it for a file that doesn't exist or with incorrect path information.  That's what the error is telling you, that the path can't be found that was supplied to the call to fs.readFile. I did the following:

1) Copied your code into a file /home/username/Desktop/test.js (Ubuntu 12.04)

2) Opened chromium web browser

3) Typed 127.0.0.1:3000//etc//fstab into the URL box and hit ENTER where 127.0.0.1:3000 causes the browser to look for the server at port 3000 on your own machine

The file /etc/fstab was read and successfully displayed into the browser window.

My guess is when you are typing in your URL you are asking for a file that is out of scope or has the wrong path.  I got the same result if I tried to find a file that wasn't there by full path:  { [Error: ENOENT, open 'whereIsMyFile'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'whereIsMyFile' }

If you do request a file that is in the same directory as your node.js script, it will not need full path.  For example, the file can read itself: 127.0.0.1:3000/test.js